# Akka stream best practice for dynamic Source and Flow controlled by websocket messages

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to implement with akka stream and alpakka the following scenario (simplified):

1. The frontend opens a websocket connection with the backend
2. Backend should wait an initialization message with some parameters (for example `bootstrapServers`, `topicName` and a `transformationMethod` that is a string parameter)
3. Once these informations are in place, backend can start the alpakka consumer to consume from topic `topicName` from `bootstrapServers` and applying some transformation to the data based on `transformationMethod`, pushing these results inside the websocket
4. Periodically, frontend can send through the websocket messages that changes the `transformationMethod` field, so that the transformation algorithm of the messages consumed from Kafka can dynamically change, based on the value of `transformationMethod` provided into the websocket.

I don't understand if it's possible to achieve this on akka stream inside a Graph, especially the dynamic part, both for the initialization of the alpakka consumer and also for the dynamic changing of the `transformationMethod` parameter.

Example:

Frontend establish connection, and after 10 second it sends trough the socket the following:

```
{"bootstrapServers": "localhost:9092", "topicName": "topic", "transformationMethod": "PLUS_ONE"}
```

Because of that, Alpakka consumer is instantiated and starts reading messages from Kafka.

Messages are flowing in Kafka, so it arrives `1` and in the websocket the frontend will receive `2` (because of the `PLUS_ONE` transformation method, that is probably placed in a `map` or a `via` with a Flow), then `2` and so frontend receives `3` and so on.

Then, frontend sends:

```
{"transformationMethod": "SQUARE"}
```

So now, from Kafka arrives `3` and the frontend will receive `9`, then `4` and so the output will be `16` ecc...

This is more or less the flow of what I would like to obtain.

I am able to create a websocket connection with Alpakka consumer that perform some sort of "static" transformations and push back the result to the websocket, it's straightforward, what I miss is this dynamic part but I'm not sure if i can implement that inside the same graph or if I need more layers (maybe with some Actor that manages the flow and will activate/change the behavior of the Alpakka consumer in real time sending messages?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably tend to implement this by spawning an actor for each websocket, prematerializing a `Source` which will receive messages from the actor (probably using `ActorSource.actorRefWithBackpressure`), building a `Sink` (likely using `ActorSink.actorRefWithBackpressure`) which adapts incoming websocket messages into control-plane messages (initialization (including the `ActorRef` associated with the prematerialized source) and transformation changes) and sends them to the actor, and then tying them together using the `handleMessagesWithSinkSource` on `WebsocketUpgrade`.

The actor you're spawning would, on receipt of the initialization message, start a stream which is feeding messages to it from Kafka; some backpressure can be fed back to Kafka by having the stream feed messages via an ask protocol which waits for an ack; in order to keep that stream alive, the actor would need to ack within a certain period of time regardless of what the downstream did, so there's a decision to be made around having the actor buffer messages or drop them.